# No render of amchart with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, wkhtmltopdf, amcharts

I have some problems with wkhtmltopdf and javascript.
On my page is a table generated with jqgrid and some graphics with amchart.

When I use wkhtmltopdf I get a blank entry to the grid and no entries at all for amchart (only the container).

Here the execution of wkhtmltopdf :

```
wkhtmltopdf --cookie-jar cookie.txt --javascript-delay 2000 --use-xserver mypage /tmp/render.pdf

QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method               ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::_q_receiveReply() called without QHttpNetworkReply, 0 bytes on socket. 
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

Can you help me?

(I am using the 0.11.0 rc1 version of wkhtmltopdf) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32bits))

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and I see that you are already using and setting --javascript-delay which is a vital part of the solution.

Apart from that you also need to specify the width and height for your chart container div in pixels, my charts started rendering when I set the width in pixels instead of a percentage value.